# must change Flask port when new css design is implemented

Tags: python, flask

I'm setting up a web with flask, but when I change the css code the design doesn't change, so i should change the new port for make new css code work.

```
#host
def runFlaskApp():
    app.run(host = '127.0.0.1', port = 5003, debug = True, threaded = True)

if __name__== "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runFlaskApp())
    t1.start()
```

Comment: The CSS is probably being cached by your browser, you should work with the cache disabled when developing

Answer (score 1):

CSS is being cached. You should implement some mechanism for cache-busting in production.
For development in Chrome and Firefox, you can open the dev tools and hit Ctrl+F5 to do hard reload.

Or when dev tools are opened right click on the refresh button and then press Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

[image]